# Remove CSS-property which was applied through stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there way to remove CSS-property which was applied through CSS stylesheet?

Example:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk9xw0kc/)

**test.css**

```
.test { background: red; }
```

**test.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

<div class="test">Foo</div>

<script>
$('.test').each(function(i, block) {
    $(this).css('background', '');
});
</script>
```

Yes, it will remove CSS-property if it was added inline:

```
Before                                        After
<div class="test" style="background: red">    <div class="test">
```

But, the question is about removing stylesheet-based properties, not inline.

Also, I understand that I could use "transparent" and it will work:

```
$(this).css('background', 'transparent');
```

But again, this is a bit out of scope of my question.

Comment: remove class test in the element

Comment: You cannot remove a CSS property. It is *always* set to something by default, even if you don't do it manually. You need to set the value to something *other* than red. The default value is `transparent`. The solution which you've deemed 'out of scope' is the only way you can do this - other than removing the rule in the stylesheet directly

Comment: Do you want to do it without removing the class (for cases when the class is more complicated than the one shown and has other properties that you don't want to remove)?

Comment: `$(this).css('background', '');` is invalid. Instead set the background to none `$(this).css('background', 'none');` [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk9xw0kc/2/)

Comment: @Pugazh - An empty string is not invalid. It has the effect of removing any *inline* `background` property, thereby letting other settings from the stylesheet take effect instead. (Which doesn't help the OP here, but still...definitely not invalid in a general sense.)

Comment: Are you doing anything else in that each otherwise you can just do `$('.test').css('background','none');` - [see this for initial values for background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background?v=control) that you can use to override your styles.  Also why is transparent out of scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the value in the style sheet, you can override it as you did in your example

```
$(this).css('background', 'transparent');
```

or have another class in your style sheet with the desired properties and replace the classes with JS

```
$(this).removeClass('test');
$(this).addClass('your-other-class');
```

Answer (score 0):

a CSS file shouldn't be modified while the website is running.

A little trick could be to **SUBSTITUTE** your currently active CSS file with another one that you customized before.

You can do it like this (you must use JQUERY)

```
$('link[href="yourfirstfile.css"]').attr('href','yoursecondfile.css');
```

or you can simply prepare a second class that will substitute your first one when you need it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a style without removing a class from the html element.  You can only do so by manipulating the DOM using javascript or updating the HTML.

But you can override the styles, by importing a new css file **after** the original one.

OR

Add style element in html **after** the css import to override the styles from the css without using javascript.

OR

By adding inline style elements to the HTML source or using Javascript.